# Python: TypeError: inet_aton() argument 1 must be str, not None

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am working with a mobile game API and a Telegram Bot. It worked when I put in a fixed Clantag, but now I wanted to let the user write a tag and add it to the link. The app then should search for the clan and get the right stats. Everything is ok but I get this message now and cannot find my mistake. Would be happy if you could help!

```
def main():
    last_update_id = None
    message = ""
    while True:
        updates = get_updates(last_update_id)
        if len(updates["result"]) > 0:
            last_update_id = get_last_update_id(updates) + 1
            message = get_last_update_Message(updates)
            clan_stats(updates, message)
```

```
def get_last_update_Message(updates):
    message = ""
    for update in updates["result"]:
        message = update["message"]
    return message["text"]
```

```
def clan_stats(updates, ID):
    #https://api.royaleapi.com/clan/1RLU78YU
    Link = '"https://api.royaleapi.com/clan/' + ID + '"'

    r=requests.get(Link, headers={"Accept":"application/json",
    "authorization":"Bearer TOKENHERE"})
    clan = r.json()
```

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Lee63225/clashroyaleclanbot.py", line 188, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/Lee63225/clashroyaleclanbot.py", line 184, in main
    clan_stats(updates, message)
  File "/home/Lee63225/clashroyaleclanbot.py", line 80, in clan_stats
    "authorization":"Bearer TOKENHERE"})
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 503, in request
    prep.url, proxies, stream, verify, cert
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 676, in merge_environment_settings
    env_proxies = get_environ_proxies(url, no_proxy=no_proxy)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 760, in get_environ_proxies
    if should_bypass_proxies(url, no_proxy=no_proxy):
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 716, in should_bypass_proxies
    if is_ipv4_address(parsed.hostname):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 640, in is_ipv4_address
    socket.inet_aton(string_ip)
TypeError: inet_aton() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

Thank you!

Comment: `get_updates` takes `None` as an argument the first time it is called; how is that defined?

Comment: What's the full traceback (which would either confirm that the problem stems from the initial call to `get_updates` or indicate the source of the problem otherwise)?

Comment: That part didnt change and worked before. I have it from a template. That is not the problem and does not occur in the traceback.

Comment: Added Full Traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should rather be

```
Link = 'https://api.royaleapi.com/clan/' + ID
```

There is some surrounding `"` in your attempt.

But now as I look, the function is called as `clan_stats(update,message)`. That "message" should be a clantag, make sure it is (as now it comes from `get_last_update_Message()`, and looks very suspicious.

Comment: But I need surrounding "" because it has to be link in the requests.get, hm? And I tried to eter a correct clantag as "message" and that didnt work.

Comment: No; the double quotes are not part of the URL. You would write `get("https://...")`, not `get('"https://..."')`.

Comment: Well, I went by the comment above that line and my suggestion assumed that a fixed URL, like `Link = 'https://api.royaleapi.com/clan/1RLU78YU'` was the one which worked. If that is not the case, you may really want to show the variant which originally worked.

Comment: Added Full Traceback.

Comment: OK let me try it.

Comment: I had this before and it worked:
`r=requests.get("https://api.royaleapi.com/clan/1RLU78YU", headers={"Accept":"application/json",
    "authorization":"Bearer TOKENHERE"})`

Thats why I thought I need those quotation marks.

Comment: `"` and `'` can be changed, but you do not need them at the same time: `print('Hello')` and `print("Hello")` will both print `Hello`. But `print('"Hello"')` and `print("'Hello'")` will also print the "inner" quotation marks, making the string different (`"Hello"` and `'Hello'` respectively). It is a convenience (that you can use the "other" quotation mark inside a string), but it can also cause a bit of confusion.